# Swift Network.Framework TLS with alternative I/O?

Tags: swift, ssl, tls1.2, network.framework

I am working on a custom protocol in Swift and am looking into Network.Framework for its TLS implementation. I'd like to have control over the I/O with the option to use something other than TCP or UDP, but I found [this github discussion](https://github.com/python-trio/trio/issues/1165) that says it is not an option to use TLS without the NWConnection TCP built-in transport.

What I am looking for is a way to interface with the TLS functions where I can pass in and receive the bytes for the protocol. The [wolfSSL library](https://www.wolfssl.com/wolfssl-alternative-io-support/) (for example) has these features, so it doesn't seem like an uncommon design choice.

Is there a way to get that level of access to the Network.Framework TLS functions?